# What's the difference between Apache Ignite and Tachyon

Tags: apache-spark, ignite, alluxio

I am new to Apache Ignite，for the Ignite and spark integration， it looks that Ignite provides an in-memory layer that the data will live across spark applications, which is the capability that Tachyon provides as an in-memory File System.
So, my question is for the in-memory File System(IGFS for ignite), what is the difference between Ignite and Tachyon? What's the pros and crons between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Ignite is a platform with many components, such as (not limited to):

- A compute engine, which allows you to run distributed computations in fork-join model (there is no dependency on Hadoop or Spark)
- A distributed JSR-107 compliant key-value storage with various persistence options and an ability to run indexed SQL queries against your data and, starting from Ignite 1.8, update your data using DML
- Distributed fault-tolerant services allowing you to run a fixed number of background processes in a cluster
- IGFS, a distributed in-memory file system
- Hadoop accelerator component
- Spark RDD integration allowing you to have an intermediate storage for results of Spark tasks
- Distributed events, messaging, etc...

If we are to look at the Ignite-Spark integration, one major feature that I would pay attention to is the ability to run *indexed* SQL queries. This may significantly improve performance of queries compared to Spark on large RDDs.

Tachyon, on the other hand, is an in-memory file system, so I would say that Tachyon itself compares to IGFS pretty close.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey..Not sure why Ignite contains too many components .. looks to me it is a hotchpotch. The more component/capability it provides, the less focus it will pay on each individual component.